# Unsupported Array Type in 'cvGetMat' - Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv, raspberry-pi

This is my Python code:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('./images/image.jpg')
cv2.imshow('Input image', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

When I run the following code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Desktop/sample.py", line 3, in <module>
cv2.imshow('Input image', img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) /tmp/pip-wheel-pd499c9i/opencv- 
python_3a15e83eee864e65b7311a199a94e9f1/opencv/modules/core/src/array.cpp:2494: error: 
(-206:Bad flag (parameter or structure field)) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in 
function 'cvGetMat'
```

Some people say that the directory might not be right, but I checked the directory and everything is fine. I even installed Numpy (version - 1.21.2).

Can anyone please help me? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 2 suggestions:

1. Make sure that your path is correct by rather than just checking, but by using the [`os.path.exists()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) method:

```
import cv2
import os

path = './images/image.jpg'
if os.path.exists(path):
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    cv2.imshow('Input image', img)
    cv2.waitKey()
```

2. If the same error occurs after placing the `if` statement, your JPG file might be of the format [CMYK](https://proofbranding.com/color-profiles-file-types/). Try opening an RGB file and see if the same error occurs.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It worked when I changed the format to a RBG type.

Comment: @AnikethChavare Glad the help!